# What is the php I need to show a Custom Field Value from a Drop Down Box, Type (Select2), in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-fields, woothemes

Currently I am using this php code to display Text for a custom field with taxonomy 'years' in a theme in wordpress, that works well

php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'years', true); (Including the php opening and closing tags)

But the problem I have is that if I want to change this Text, to a Drop Down Box (a select2 type), to let choose different options to the users, I cannot find how to display the values correctly.

Any body has any idea of how to display correctly the value of a custom field froma Drop Down selec2 type ?

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would accomplish this.

1. On your post or page, add the custom field. So if you have a custom field of 'years' we'll add 2013 and 2014 and 2015 as 3 entries. Save your post/page.
2. This creates an array for this custom field that you can iterate through. see here for code. http://pastebin.com/Ungm3WZW

FYI - I referenced the codex for http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gregg, actually I have used your reference code but In the result I see just have number values of the array, and this number is shown as a select button not just as text. Do you know how I can fix this. How you add the values you mentioned to the array like the 2013 and 2014 and 2015 like you mentioned. Thanks a lot

Comment: I thought you wanted a drop down box? That was what my code was for. You can modify my code in pastebin to remove the select and options and just echo out the $year.